# Under what scenario an arbitrary space in the browser will not available to the window object?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm reading MDN documentation about the [Screen width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/width) property in the Screen interface, and the documentation states the following:

> Note that not all of the width given by this property may be available to the window itself. **When other widgets occupy space that cannot be used by the window object**, there is a difference in window.screen.width and window.screen.availWidth

When does the bolded scenario occur? The only thing that comes to mind is if there is a frame or iframe embedded on the page, but even then I'm unable to see the difference.

Is it safe to assume that that `window.screen.width` and `window.screen.availWidth` will always be identical the vast majority of the time?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456582/screen-width-and-screen-availwidth-difference-in-javascript

Comment: When they refer to widgets, it almost sounds like Developer Tools. Technically, the window is much wider, but the tools are contracting the viewport. That's my best guess.